# Getting net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at location when pass java.awt.Image as parameter

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports

I get the exception above when I try to display an image chosen from *JFileChooser* for passing to *JasperReports* report, can anyone please help me to figure out it?

The steps I followed are:

1. added a  parameter named photo via report inspector and set its parameter class to Object
2. dragged and dropped an image from the palette and gave its expression class as *java.awt.Image* and *Image Expression* to `$P{photo}`

This is the image element in .jrxml file

```xml
<image>
   <reportElement x="315" y="0" width="195" height="77" uuid="59390988-25fc-4d62-80c4-bc19b80b0fa0"/>
   <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{photo}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

These are the code examples i referred and used to generate the report.

```
Image photo;
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

private void getPicture() {
    fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "gif", "bmp"));
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(fc.getCurrentDirectory());

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        icon = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(350, 350, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        photo = icon.getImage();
    }

    if (photo == null) {
        System.out.println("null");
    }

    System.out.println("path= " + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("photo", photo);

    generateReports(param);
}


private void generateReports(Map param) {
    try {

        String source = "C:\\newReport.jrxml";

        if (new File(source).exists() == false) {
            System.out.println("Please  report Source does not exist");
            return;
        }

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(source);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("reports Error " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your xml and do this, the location of my image is as seen below it works for me thanks

imageExpression>![CDATA["src\Forms\leaf_banner_gray.png

Answer (score 0):

The below line of code working fine when I do preview of the PDF from JasperStudio but not while creating PDF from Java.

```
<imageExpression>![CDATA["src\Forms\leaf_banner_gray.png"]]</imageExpression>
```

Finally, we found the solution.

```
//declared a property leafBanner of type InputStream
<parameter name="leafBanner" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
//leafBanner property has been used below
<imageExpression>![CDATA[$P{leafBanner}]]</imageExpression>
```

Below is the code to pass image as stream from Java.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
File leafBanner= ResourceUtils.getFile("src//main//resources//images//leafBanner.PNG");
FileInputStream leafBannerStream = new FileInputStream(leafBanner);
params.put("leafBanner", leafBannerStream);
```